# How do I view an X display on a remote host from OSX

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox, x11, x11forwarding, selenium

I'm running an X server in a under `xvfb` in an Ubuntu 14.04 Virtualbox VM.

The X display is used to run Firefox and Chrome for some Selenium tests. I want to be able to view the contents of this display in real-time from OSX, to debug these tests.

Is this possible from OSX?

My initial thought was to use `ssh -x`, but that seems to assume that the process is being started by my SSH session. In this case a process inside the VM is launching the process that runs under the X display - I just want to attach to the display to see what's going on.

Comment: You could just run a VNC server on it and then connect via Screen Sharing.